# PowerChute vMA server shuts down ESXi host after boot

Tags: ups, shutdown, apc-smart-ups

I've ran into a critical problem first time installing and configuring a UPS connected to a server.

Whenever I boot up the vMA server, ESXi starts shutting down all the VM's and then itself. It's like there's a power outage every time I start the vMA.

Short info about my setup:

- 12 VM's running on the ESXi host
- Server model: HP ProLiant DL380p Gen8
- APC model: SMT2200RMI2U without NMC
- vMA Appliance version: 6.0.0.0 Build 2503728
- PowerChute Business Edition 5 Node - v9.1.1

So from the start I followed this guide: http://goo.gl/cvQqzU
Got to Page 13, step 25 and then suddenly ESXi shut down.
For configuring the vMA, installing PowerChute and everything I followed this guide on youtube: https://youtu.be/fQ7gUSPPUg8 as there were nothing about it in the guide from above.

The UPS is connected with a RJ45(from UPS) to DB9 serial cable(HP Server) 
The UPS does not have a network management card.

Is there anyone who knows what could cause this to happen?
Anyone who has had the same problem before?

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend using UPS shutdown for your VMware systems. There's a lot more to lose by doing so, as the process is [difficult to control and manage properly](https://serverfault.com/questions/338120/how-to-properly-shutdown-esxi-cluster-after-power-outage).

See: [VMware ESXi shutdown triggered by APC UPS connected via USB](https://serverfault.com/questions/462993/vmware-esxi-shutdown-triggered-by-apc-ups-connected-via-usb)

In this case, you have high quality server equipment, a big UPS and out-of-band management (ILO). Leverage them.

In addition, if you define your VM startup/shutdown rules, the (single) host will bring your systems up in order.

In the event you need an orderly shutdown, simply pressing the power button once on that system will shut down the VMs in sequence and power off the system.